# How to pass a cell array to fullfile

Tags: matlab, filepath

How do I pass a cell array like

```
pathParts = {'D:', 'foo', 'matic'}
```

to `fullfile` to obtain a complete path (i.e. `D:\foo\matic`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follows:

```
fullfile(pathParts{:})
```

By colon indexing of a cell array, MATLAB will return a [comma separated list](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). This you can then easily pass to other functions.